Inline CSS in default value for Draft.js does not work
I have written a tiny component for Drafj.js to have defaultValue prop. Everything works well, But after load defaultValue, Inline css remove from my HTML!
export function Editor({ ...props }) {
    const [editorState, setEditorState] = useState<any>(null)

    useEffect(() => {
        if (props?.defaultValue) {
            const blocksFromHTML: any = convertFromHTML(props?.defaultValue)
            setEditorState(EditorState.createWithContent(ContentState.createFromBlockArray(blocksFromHTML)))
        }
    }, [props?.defaultValue])

    const stateChange = (estate: any) => {
        setEditorState(estate)
    }
    if (props?.noeditor) {
        return <><Label htmlFor={props?.id}>{props.title}</Label>
            <Textarea name={props?.name}></Textarea>
        </>
    }

    return <><Label htmlFor={props?.id}>{props.title}</Label><DraftEditor
        editorState={editorState}
        onEditorStateChange={stateChange}
    /><textarea className="hidden" name={props?.name} value={editorState ? draftToHtml(convertToRaw(editorState?.getCurrentContent() || "")) : ""}></textarea></>;
}


Usage :
<Editor name="short_content" title={t("Short Content")} defaultValue={edit?.short_content || ""} />

When I save below HTML code in my database:
<p><span style="color: rgb(97,189,109);"><strong>1000 test</strong></span><strong> test </strong></p>

After setting it to defaultValue inline CSS will be removed from my editor
